# Limit to infinity and its negation

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Hopefully not too obvious.

Definition of limit to infinity and its negation.

Are the statements below correct? Thanks.

1) $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty$:

For every $N>0 $ there is a $M >0$ s.t.

$x > M$ implies $f(x)>N$.

Negation:

There is a $N>0$ s.t. for every $M >0$ there is a

$x >M$ s.t. $ f(x) \le N$.

Sequences:

2)For  all $x_n$ with $\lim  x_n =\infty$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)= \infty$:

For every $N>0$ there is a $n_0$ s. t.

$n \ge n_0$ implies $f(x_n)> N$.

Negation:

There is $N >0$, s.t.  for every $n_0$ there is a

$n \ge n_0$ with $f(x_n)\le N$.

Comment: @PeterSzilas It looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both look fine and correct to me.

My only note is that we don't need $\forall N>0$ in the definition since it suffices to state $\forall N$.