# negating quantifiers

Tags: real-analysis, logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to understand the rules of negating quantifiers. For example the definition of convergence for a null sequence is

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ such that $|a_{n}| < \epsilon, \forall n > N$

Now negating, with the help of the comments I get

$\exists \epsilon > 0, ¬ \exists N$ such that $|a_{n}| < \epsilon, \exists n ¬ > N$.

which rewriting it a bit is

$\exists \epsilon > 0 $ such that for all $N, |a_{n}| \geq \epsilon, \exists n \leq N$

Comment: You put a negation sign in front of $\forall$ and you get $\exists \lnot$.

Comment: Now you have $\exists \epsilon \ \lnot \exists N$. Moving inside again you get : $\exists \epsilon \ \forall N \lnot$.

Comment: And so on with $\lnot \forall n$.

Comment: The not does not go before $\epsilon \gt 0$ it goes before the $\forall$.  It would read there exists an epsilon $\gt 0$ such that it is not true that for all $x$...

Comment: Thanks, I'll make an edit.

Comment: Examples :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453429/limit-to-infinity-and-its-negation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to write the original statement is
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \forall n \gt N, |a_{n}| < \epsilon$$
Then the negation is 
$$\lnot\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \forall n \gt N, |a_{n}| < \epsilon\\
\exists \epsilon > 0,\lnot \exists N \forall n \gt N,|a_{n}| < \epsilon\\
\exists \epsilon > 0,\forall N \lnot\forall n \gt N, |a_{n}| < \epsilon\\
\exists \epsilon > 0,\forall N \exists n \gt N, |a_{n}| \gt \epsilon$$