# What is the epsilon-delta definition for the limit in the case of $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, epsilon-delta

I have managed to find the definition for all the other cases except for this one.  I searched on the internet for a long while about it, and couldn't find it, and this is my last resort.

Comment: For all $Y$ there is $X$ such that if $x>X$ then $f(x)>Y$

Comment: Perhaps of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453429/limit-to-infinity-and-its-negation

Answer (score 2):

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$ means that, for all $Y$, there is $X$, such that, if $x>X$, then $f(x)>Y$.

A statement for sequences similar to this statement for functions can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Infinite_limits).